# is there a better dynamic way to replace if any digit except 0 exists using sed/awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

Team,
my output is below and I want to replace all non-zeros after comma to boolean 1.

```
DA:74,0
DA:75,0
DA:79,3 < NON BOOLEAN
DA:80,3 < NON BOOLEAN
DA:81,3 < NON BOOLEAN
DA:82,4 < NON BOOLEAN
DA:83,1
```

so I did this
`sed 's/,[1-999]/,1/g'`

but I can't be increasing 999 to 9999 kind of manual. is there a dynamic way that if no 0 then replace with one. 1

expected output

```
DA:74,0
DA:75,0
DA:79,1
DA:80,1
DA:81,1
DA:82,1
DA:83,1
```

possible values are any combinations
like

```
DA:108,23
DA:110,101
DA:111,098
DA:112,100
```

all above should be replaced by 1. so only case it should replace is when there is single digit 0 or single digit 1.

so any non-zero number with a comma before should be replaced.

Comment: `[1-999]` = `[1-9]` and only matches a single digit other than `0`.

Comment: sorry did not understand. my goal is any number other 0 exists should be replaced by 1. so can you please suggest how can i achieve? not sure what -1 means to my question.

Comment: `,[1-999]` already matches a comma and then a non-`0` digit. Do you want to say you can have leading zeros? Then use `,0*[1-9]`.

Comment: Ok, since you are replacing, `,0*[1-9][0-9]*` will do.

Comment: Can `< NON BOOLEAN` ever be other text such as `< FOO 1,2 BAR`?

Comment: does the file contain the literal string `< NON BOOLEAN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
sed -E 's/,([1-9]|[0-9]{2,})$/,1/'
```

It will find all lines ending with (comma, single digit != 0) or (comma, multiple digits) and replace them with `,1`

Demo [here](https://ideone.com/l0K8ct).

Comment: thanks works but with `-i` it is not working to replace in file.

Comment: @AhmFM, what do you mean? `sed -Ei 's/,([1-9]|[0-9]{2,})$/,1/' filename` works as intended, at least in Ubuntu.

Comment: my bad, it was MAC

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,0*[1-9].*/,1/' file
```

Replace any number greater than zero following the first `,` with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- the literal string `< NON BOOLEAN` does not exist in the file
- there is only one comma per line
- anything other than a `0` (eg, negative number, alphanumeric string) after the comma is converted to a `1`

Adding some additional data:

```
$ cat filex
DA:74,0
DA:75,0
DA:79,3
DA:80,3
DA:81,3
DA:82,4
DA:83,1
DA:104,-1
DA:105,0123
DA:106,abc
DA:107,
DA:108,23
DA:110,101
DA:111,098
DA:112,100
```

One `awk` approach:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} $NF!=0 {$NF=1} 1' filex
DA:74,0
DA:75,0
DA:79,1
DA:80,1
DA:81,1
DA:82,1
DA:83,1
DA:104,1
DA:105,1
DA:106,1
DA:107,1
DA:108,1
DA:110,1
DA:111,1
DA:112,1
```

Answer (score 1):

If `< NON BOOLEAN` doesn't really exist in your input and you just want the value after the `,` to be a 1 if non-zero or 0 otherwise then:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$NF=($NF ? 1 : 0)} 1' file
DA:74,0
DA:75,0
DA:79,1
DA:80,1
DA:81,1
DA:82,1
DA:83,1
```